# How to Migrate from Raid 0 to Raid 5. Dell Server t430

Tags: raid, dell

I have a Dell PowerEdge T430 Server with Windows Server 2016. The point is that now it's configured as a raid 0, and the client wants to change it to a Raid 5.

I am afraid as if changing this could make a loss of data. I understand that changing the configuration through the Bios everything should go fine. If someone could tell me what are the most important points to take in mind for the migration it would be very appreciated.

Comment: You understand that "changing the configuration through the BIOS should go fine." From where do you understand that?

Comment: it's a way of talking, i mean assuming there is no problem on doing so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you have three disks, each 1TB in size. In a RAID0 configuration, each disk is chained together forming a virtual disk of 3TB. Assume you have 2.5TB of data on this virtual disk.

Now you want to convert those three disks from a RAID0 configuration to a RAID5 configuration that can only store 2TB of data. The remaining 1TB is required for the parity checks.

Do you imagine doing this *without* losing data?

The steps to go through are:

- Copy all data to external storage (or other disks).
- Format your disks as a RAID5 array instead of a RAID0 array.
- Copy over all data from external storage to the RAID5 array.

Assuming Windows server is installed on this RAID0 array, I would only copy over the configuration files and the data. Then do a clean install of Windows server once you've converted from RAID0 to RAID5. Finally copy the configuration and data files back to the essentially new server.

Comment: All that being said: Don't use RAID5 to begin with. It is outdated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Agreed. RAID6 or RAID10 should be used instead.

Comment: @Sven Not true if you're running on SSD. The URE issues that killed RAID5 don't exist in the SSD environment.

Comment: After the migration is completed it's possible to put a ghost image done when  it was Raid 0?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand that question.

Comment: I mean Norton Ghost, or Acronist image... it's a image of a partiton and the idea is to paste the image so i don't need to install any software again. I don't know if this works

Answer (score 5):

Dell Raid controllers support the reconfiguration from Raid 0 to Raid 5 (or Raid 6). (Except you use a H330 controller)

For the reconfiguration from RAID 0 to RAID 5/6 you will need to add one or more drives.

Details: [Reconfiguration Of Virtual Disks on the PowerEdge RAID Controller](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln156106/reconfiguration-of-virtual-disks-on-the-poweredge-raid-controller-perc-h310-h710-h710p-and-h810?lang=en)

First you have to apply the additional disks. The reconfiguration is menu driven. These are the main steps on a H730 controller:

- Virtual disk Manamgment
- Reconfigure virtual disks
- Add physical discs
- Apply changes
- .. Follow the menu

Before starting I would check for firmware updates and perform a system backup.

Good luck!